# Set focus to an input within a Bootstrap TabContent on tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to set focus to "inputOne" input when tabOne is selected, and set focus to "inputTwo" when tabTwo is selected.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tabOne" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#tabTwo" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li> 
</ul>

<div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabOne">
           <input type="text" id="inputOne" />
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabTwo">
           <input type="text" id="inputTwo" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CdeUsv7LYi)

**JS**:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = e.target.attributes.href.value;
  $(target +' input').focus();
})
```

You can find doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) :

Comment: Ive changed (target +' input') to ('#inputTwo') and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/d4A1aywY3w   : On tab One, input one is focused, same for #2...

Comment: And if i have several inputs on each tab, and want to select a specific one on each tab?

Comment: In that circumstance I'd probably add an attribute to the tab links like `data-focus="#inputTwo"`, then grab that in the function as the target to select: `target = $(e.target).attr('data-focus'); $(target).focus();`

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use the show event in addition to my current code

Comment: simple and helpful..tks

Comment: I am using angularJs (version 1.5+). I have the focus directive, how can I incorporate your suggestion into it? My markup is  <ul class="nav nav-pills"><li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#paymentTypes" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.EditPaymentTypeForm.$invalid]">General</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#paymentInfo" 
                                   ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.PaymentInformationForm.$invalid]">Information</a></li> </ul> I want the first input in each tab to be focused when activated

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on the bootstrap "shown" event for the tabs to handle this:

```
$(".nav-tabs a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(event) {
    $(event.target.href.value + " input").focus();
});
```

more info on the tab event: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following jquery code :

```
$( "#tabOne" ).click(function() {
  $( "#inputOne" ).focusin()        
});
```

Do the same thing for `tabTwo` also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but its not working... Should i put an ID on the tab header and check its click event instead of tabContent div ID?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(). have you wrote the function inside this